# What is an Eigenbasis and how do I calculate it with the information below.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, proof-explanation

I have the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 4 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

I've calculated the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors as follows with help in a previous question:

$\lambda = 2$ or $8$

$$E_{\lambda = 2} = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} v_1\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ \end{bmatrix} = a\begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 1\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 0\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \mid a, b \in \mathbb R \right\}$$

$$E_{\lambda = 8} = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} v_1\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ \end{bmatrix} = a \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix} \mid \mathbb R\right\}$$

Is the Eigenbasis simply:

$$E_{\lambda = 2} = \operatorname{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 1\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 0\\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix} \right) $$

$$E_{\lambda = 8} = \operatorname{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An eigenbasis is a basis in which every vector is an eigenvector.

In your case,
$$
\left\{
\pmatrix{-1\\1\\0},
\pmatrix{-1\\0\\1},
\pmatrix{1\\1\\1}
\right\}
$$
is an eigenbasis for your matrix $A$.

Comment: The question I'm trying to answer says: Find a basis for each eigenspace of A. Is it the same answer?

Comment: The first two form a basis of one eigenspace, and the second two form a basis of the other.  So this isn't *quite* the same answer, but it is certainly related.

Comment: does it matter which pairs you pick or can it be any two of the three? Do the first two provide a basis in R^2 and the second and third provide a basis in R^3

Comment: Yes, it does matter which pair (or more generally, which groups) you pick. The first two form a basis of $E_{\lambda = 2}$ because they are a maximal linearly independent set of eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 2$.  In other words, you need to group the eigenvectors according to their eigenvalues.

Comment: All of these vectors are elements of $\Bbb R^3$.  $E_{\lambda = 2}$ is a *2-dimensional subspace* of $\Bbb R^3$, while $E_{\lambda = 8}$ is a *1-dimensional subspace* of $\Bbb R^3$.  If we take all of them together, the eigenvectors we've chosen form a basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

To help add some important concepts to eigenvalues and eigenvectors I will drag in another matrix.

$${\bf A} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}2&2\\0&2\end{array}\right]$$

if we solve

$$|{\bf A}-\lambda {\bf I}| = 0 \Leftrightarrow (2-\lambda)^2 = 0$$, we see that 2 is an eigenvalue that occurs twice. But if we solve 
$${\bf A}-2 {\bf I} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{cc|c}0&2&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$ So only first component is actually $\neq 0$. This brings up the concepts of geometric dimensionality and algebraic dimensionality. $[0,1]^t$ is a [Generalized eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) belonging to the same generalized eigenspace as $[1,0]^t$ which is the "true eigenvector".